# Replacement mouse "feet"?

Tags: mouse

The **plastic skid pad "feet" on the bottom of my Logitech G9 mouse** (which I love!) are getting rather worn down -- to the point that the outer shell of the mouse scrapes on the mousepad a bit.

[image]

I've had the mouse for about ~2 years now so it does get a lot (I mean *lot* of use). However, I hate having to buy a new mouse when I only need replacement "feet".

Where can I obtain replacement mouse feet? Is this even possible?

**EDIT**: I just received the [HyperGlide replacement mouse feet for the G9](http://www.google.com/search?q=hyperglide+mouse+skates+g9) in the mail, and they work great! Perfectly cut to exactly the right size, very smooth mouse action, *and* you get two full sets for $14 so it's not as expensive as I thought.

Comment: -1 no freehand circles.  (kidding!)  seriously tho, i take it you're talking about the oblong dark shapes in the pic?  does it feel like a sort of soft plastic?  i don't know of replacement parts offhand but am thinking a DIY match-materials,-shape-and-add-glue would work.

Comment: Jeff these things are like with the Gilette razors, when the rubbers gone it's time to replace 'em!

Comment: People still use mousepads? :-) I also didn't know you could replace the feet. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Mouse feet are apparently made of teflon aka [Polytetrafluoroethylene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytetrafluoroethylene).

I was resigned to buying a broken G9 on eBay and salvaging its feet, but apparently, much to my surprise, it *is* possible to buy aftermarket mouse feet aka slider pads.

Here are two from HyperGlide:

- [Ulti-Mat Add 'n Slide - Teflon Gaming Mouse Feet](http://www.frozencpu.com/products/3088/pad-92/Ulti-Mat_Add_n_Slide_-_Teflon_Gaming_Mouse_Feet.html) (0.5mm thick)
- [Hyperglide Mouse Skates G-9](http://www.frozencpu.com/products/7056/pad-138/Hyperglide_Mouse_Skates_G-9_-_Logitech_G9.html) (0.8mm thick)

http://www.slicksurf.com/ also sells a variety of replacement mouse feet, both custom fit to particular mice and generic one-size-fits-all. However, they don't have anything for the G9, and I saw one user review that was negative:

> Please don't recommend Slicksurf to me. I've tried those and I thought they were just pieces of plastic that were not slick at all. Not to mention they were not cut precisely like other feet I've bought. Furthermore, because of their hardness, I felt like I was grinding into my mousepad everytime I used my mouse with those things on (Archetype rough mousepad).

The reason I listed the thickness, above, is that I need to be careful that I'm *not* getting flimsy, ultra-thin teflon **tape** (I've tried this before, and it sucks), but actual **teflon plastic feet**.

I also found a video of somebody applying the HyperGlide custom mouse feet, and they indeed look like replacement slider pads:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9aJt9Ei1HXo

Also **check eBay** as I found a number of HK vendors selling good thick teflon G9 feet for cheap there too.

Comment: Woah, I'll have to remember this for when my g5 runs down. I figured the little things couldn't last forever, anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Your mouse is a Logitech one, and they have an excellent customer support.

Just [contact their support by mail](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/support_downloads/support_contactus/), explain your situation, that you need replacement feet, and they will most likely ask you for a delivery address, to **send you new feet for free**. You can be sure that these ones will match, moreover, as they will be official.

I did that several times for my past mice, and they always sent. One thing which is great without a doubt with Logitech, from my personal experience, it's their support.

Comment: Good suggestion! I used the form and sent them the info. It's weird because the form asks for the serial number of the mouse and I can't find one printed on it anywhere. I'll update here with what happens..

Comment: @Jeff - if it's not under the mouse, it's on the sticker next to the usb plug. Assuming you haven't thrown that away :P Try to find your invoice or something, in case they ask you for it.

Comment: no response whatsoever from Logitech to date

Comment: @Jeff - hmm, that's surprising. I was used to quite fast answers from them. Though last time I used it was 2 years ago, so it might have changed since.

Comment: @Jeff - any answer since, by the way?

Answer (score 1):

eBay is a great place to look for replacement mouse feet, and not just from a broken mouse. When I bought a Microsoft Habu (which I love), it first came minus one of the pads (it was 2nd hand).  I found replacements on eBay for $3 - hard to beat that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is Gnoupi's one but YES there are aftermarket mouse feet. There are usually sold as rectangular self-adhesive pads that you have to cut the shape you want.

Have a look on gaming mice manufacturer websites such as [Razer](http://store.razerzone.com/store/razerusa/en_US/pd/productID.173851300/categoryId.35096200) (these are pre-cut), Mionix and probably Roccat, SteelSeries, ... You can also check computer shops (solid's or online!). It depends where you live, i know about newegg.com in USA for exemple...